# Applicationhost.config changes after project rebuild. How to prevent that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, applicationhost

I have complex C# ASP .Net MVC web application which requires specific non standard IIS configuration to be defined. The thing is I have to set up this configuration manually after each project rebuild and before each project start because every time IIS configuration is changing. Why? How can I prevent that or, at least, where should I setup the way this configuration is supposed to change?